# Disable access request for all SharePoint online Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

When users create SharePoint sites, By default access requests and Sharing are enabled. I would like to disable this feature globally on my SharePoint online Tenant.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the powershell in the article below:

To change access request Emails of all sites in a site collection or tenant：

[SharePoint Online: PowerShell to Change Access Request Email for All Sites](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/change-access-request-email-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html)

To disable access request, simply clear the Email value.

Please note: 
Microsoft provides third-party contact information to help you find technical support. This contact information may change without notice. Microsoft does not guarantee the accuracy of this third-party contact information.

Comment: It won't disable it for all SharePoint sites. I am looking for a solution to disable it completely for all sites.

Comment: I've updated my reply.